# Description of kernel.printk values

Tags: linux, kernel, logs, sysctl

Between Debian 5 and 6, the default suggested value for kernel.printk in `/etc/sysctl.conf` was changed from `kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7` to `kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3`.  I understand that the first value corresponds to what is going to the console.  What are the next 3 values for?

Do the numerical values have the same meaning as the syslog log levels?  Or do they have different definitions?

Am I missing some documentation in my searching, or is the only location to figure this out the kernel source.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sysctl settings are documented in [`Documentation/sysctl/*.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/) in the kernel source tree. On Debian, install [`linux-doc`](http://packages.debian.org/linux-doc) to have the documentation in `usr/share/doc/linux-doc-*/Documentation/` (most distributions have a similar package). From [`Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt):

> The four values in `printk` denote: `console_loglevel`,
>   `default_message_loglevel`, `minimum_console_loglevel` and
>   `default_console_loglevel` respectively.
>
> These values influence `printk()` behavior when printing or
>   logging error messages. See [`man 2 syslog`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syslog.2.html) for more info on
>   the different loglevels.
>
> - `console_loglevel`: messages with a higher priority than
>     this will be printed to the console
> - `default_message_loglevel`: messages without an explicit priority
>     will be printed with this priority
> - `minimum_console_loglevel`: minimum (highest) value to which
>     console_loglevel can be set
> - `default_console_loglevel`: default value for `console_loglevel`

I don't find any clear prose explanation of what `default_console_loglevel` is used for. In the [Linux kernel source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux), the `kernel.printk` sysctl sets [`console_printk`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/printk.h#L27). The `default_console_loglevel` field doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: This Debian bug [526855](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=526855), which is the origin of the change,  seemed to suggest that there are some conditions where klogd may reset console_loglevel to default_console_loglevel when it calls some kernel function.

Comment: @Zoredache: Ah. [It did back then](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.18/kernel/printk.c#L292), but [no longer](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/kernel/printk.c#L386). The setting only stopped being used in the very kernel version shipped by the current Debian stable, which explains why the setup scripts still support it.

Answer (score 8):

Description of `kernel.printk` values

- "0" → Emergency messages, system is about to crash or is unstable pr_emerg
- "1" → Something bad happened and action must be taken immediately pr_alert
- "2" → A critical condition occurred like a serious hardware/software failure pr_crit
- "3" → An error condition, often used by drivers to indicate difficulties with the hardware pr_err
- "4" → A warning, meaning nothing serious by itself but might indicate problems pr_warning
- "5" → Nothing serious, but notably nevertheless. Often used to report security events. pr_notice
- "6" → Informational message e.g. startup information at driver initialization pr_info
- "7" → Debug messages pr_debug, pr_devel if DEBUG is defined
- KERN_DEFAULT "d" The default kernel loglevel
- KERN_CONT "" "continued" line of log printout (only done after a line that had no enclosing)