# How do I prevent system information from being displayed on a terminal?

Tags: linux, kernel, terminal, logs, console

I'm working on a curses GUI that is supposed to start up automatically on boot-up in the default linux terminal (I have no X server installed).  I have this working great, but I have a problem where shortly after my curses application starts, the OS will dump some information to the terminal, which messes up my GUI.  Something about "read-ahead cache" pops up every time.  I have also seen messages displayed when I insert a USB flash drive or some other device.

Is there a way to prevent these messages from being sent to /dev/tty1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the command `dmesg -n1` to prevent all messages, except panic messages, from appearing on the console.

To make this change permanent, modify your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file to include the following setting (the first `3` is the important part).

```
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
```

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13019/description-of-kernel-printk-values) for information on the kernel.printk values.