# Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) - Possible missing firmware (*.huc*; *.guc*; *.dmc* for module i915)

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, upgrade, firmware

After upgrading the linux-kernel on a Debian `testing` System:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)  
          Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-7-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: TOSHIBA
  Hardware Model: PORTEGE R30-A
Firmware Version: Version 4.20
     GNOME Shell: 43.4
```

I get the following lines printed while the boot-image is being generated:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-7-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_huc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_69.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_guc_70.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_12.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_03.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_dmc_ver2_02.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adls_dmc_ver2_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_16.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg2_dmc_ver2_07.bin for module i915
```

**Does anyone know, what packet(s) needs to be installed to supply my system with the appropriate drivers/kernel-modules?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that these are only “possibly missing”, and in fact your laptop doesn’t need them and there’s no benefit in installing them for that specific model (which has an Intel HD Graphics 4600 integrated GPU, which doesn’t use host-provided firmware).

These firmware files are provided by [`firmware-misc-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/firmware-misc-nonfree). To install that, you need to enable the non-free-firmware repositories:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/bookworm[^ ]* main$/& non-free-firmware/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This adds the non-free-firmware repository to any line describing a Bookworm repository with only the main component.

Then update and install:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

See also [How to solve "W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915" with FOSS only? (without any non-free packages)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713288/86440)